# Return row from CSV, if matches two criteria

Tags: python, csv

The following script works where REPORT_TYPE is SOD, but what if I want it also to have the criteria of a field called DATE in my CSV to be equal to 10-24-2017? The format of the DATE field also includes hours, minutes, seconds, but I want to ignore them (e.g. 10-24-2017T23:59:00).

```
path = "C:/python-testing/*.csv"

for fname in glob.glob(path):
print(fname)

with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = [row for row in reader if row['REPORT_TYPE'] == 'SOD  ']

for row in rows:
    print row
```

I tried the following but it does not like the AND in there and gives me an invalid syntax error.

```
rows = [row for row in reader if row['REPORT_TYPE'] == 'SOD  ' AND ['DATE'] like '10-24-2017%']
```

Comment: what is `like`?

Comment: I thought I would need 'like' to be the operator since I am using a wild card. But I am not sure.

Comment: use `'10-24-2017' in ['DATE']`

Comment: Before your code gets too complicated, have a look at David Beazley's talks about generators and how to chain them. For example, you could create a `def with_report_type(type, rows): return (row for row in rows if ... == type)` and then use `rows = with_date('10-27-2017', with_type('SOD   ', reader))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't have LIKE operator (unlike SQL).

So you can use the [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method:

```
rows = [
  row 
  for row in reader 
  if row['REPORT_TYPE'] == 'SOD  ' 
     and row['DATE'].startswith('10-24-2017')
]
```

Also, use lowercase `and`, because Python's identifiers/keywords are case-sensitive (again, UNLiKE SqL).